# [[noreturn]] function pointer

Tags: c++, c++11, clang, function-pointers, noreturn

When I use clang (`version 3.4 (trunk 194574)`) to compile this:

```
typedef void (* FunctionThatNeverReturns [[ noreturn ]])();
```

I get this:

```
error: 'noreturn' attribute only applies to functions and methods
```

That surprises me because it worked perfectly fine with an older version of clang.

So how can I define a pointer to a `[[ noreturn ]]` function?

I need this because I'm calling the function pointer inside a `[[ noreturn ]]` function which obviously produces a warning if the function pointer is not marked as noreturn.

Oh, and this works:

```
typedef void (* FunctionThatNeverReturns [[ gnu::noreturn ]])();
```

But is there no compiler-independent solution?

Comment: You can't? Attributes don't make part of types.

Comment: @R.MartinhoFernandes So it once worked due to a bug in clang?

Comment: @R.MartinhoFernandes: According to my Standard, that isn't true in general.  And the error message concurs.  It's `[[noreturn]]` in particular that doesn't apply to types.

Comment: @BenVoigt Compilers are allowed to ignore attributes they don't know. I doubt that mixes well with anything else. Can you quote something?

Comment: (Also note that there's a difference between being able to apply an attribute to a typedef and using the attribute to produce distinct types)

Comment: 7.6.1p1 "Attributes specify additional information for various source constructs such as types, variables, names,
blocks, or translation units."

Comment: @Ben that's not enough. That information is merely informative since attributes can simply be ignored, and as a rule do not have any semantic effects; they could not be ignored otherwise. Granted, the committee broke their own rule with `[[noreturn]]`, but some of its members see that as a mistake.

Comment: I don't see how "can be ignored" means "no semantics".  It simply means that the additional semantics are optional, not mandatory.  For example, expressly permitting additional optimizations at the expense of floating-point precision.  Or a request to run a particular function on a hardware accelerator.

Comment: Fair enough. I should have been clearer. They can change semantics that are outside the abstract machine, as usual. That optimisation was already allowed without the attribute. However, making distinct types as intended here would diverge from the abstract machine semantics.

Comment: And sorry if I seem obnoxious, but I thought up an example that expresses what I mean even clearer: http://ideone.com/TXfvk1. Note how it is not about implicit conversions or any such thing. The two types are actually just one and the same. C++ does not have a way to express the type of "functions that take an int and never return". There's a way to express a function that takes an int and never returns, but its type is the same as the type of "functions that take an int".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As indicated in the comments, this is apparently prohibited by the standard.

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
typedef void (* FunctionThatNeverReturns)() [[ noreturn ]];
```

In your original, the specifier is placed such that it applies to the pointer and not the object pointed to.  But a noreturn pointer makes no sense at all, you're trying to typedef a pointer to a noreturn function.

Demo: http://ideone.com/9mBR9x

Comment: FWIW, clang rejects this code claiming [[noreturn]] cannot be applied to types.

Comment: @R.MartinhoFernandes: Yes, g++ seems to know something is wrong but it never tells you what.

Answer (score 0):

This version seems to compile as intended :

```
[[noreturn]] void AFunctionThatDoesNotReturn() {}
using FunctionThatNeverReturns = std::add_pointer_t<decltype(AFunctionThatDoesNotReturn)>;
```

But the compiler fail at validation we actually assing a nonreturn function pointer to the pointer : https://ideone.com/YAo73S